# Composer & composer.lock in GIT and merge conflicts

Tags: php, git, laravel, merge, composer-php

Here's our situation :

We have 3 different Laravel projects and all 3 projects rely on our Core project.
This Core project is a separate Laravel package hosted on our private repo and is used as a dependency for other projects.

Before, whenever something would change in the Core project we woud just run a composer update ourvendor/ourcorepackage on our servers for each project to pull in the core changes. However as of lately composer seems to suffer from serious memory issues when we try to run the update on our Digital Ocean staging environment with 512 MB Ram. See : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898

The solution I always come across is people saying that you should always run composer install on your production servers. I can relate to that in terms of security because it can be dangerous if you update to a new version of some 3rd party package that can possibly break your code. But in our case we only update our own core package so we know what we're doing but this memory issue forces us to use the composer install method because it is less memory demanding.

So basically this is our current workflow :

1. When something changes in our core package we need to run a composer
   update ourvendor/ourpackage on each project LOCALLY This generates a
   composer.lock file
2. We commit the composer.lock file in our repo
3. On the servers for each project we run a git pull and run a composer
   install. This will only update our core package and runs much faster
   and has no memory issues vs composer update

However this solution raises 2 issues :

1. Since we're working with multiple devs on the same project we sometimes end up having merge conflicts for the composer.lock file when pulling in the changes locally.
2. Running a git pull on the server gives an error : Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: composer.lock
   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

So what am I supposed to do here? Before the pull on the server remove the composer.lock file?
How should we handle the merge conflicts for the composer.lock file?

It's a shame that composer update suffers from memory issues because that method seems much more logical. Just update the package you want and no hassle with the composer.lock file..

Please advice how a correct workflow with GIT and composer should be in our case and how to solve the conflicts above ?

Many thanks for your input

Comment: http://blog.doh.ms/2016/11/28/solving-conflicts-in-composer-lock/

Comment: Related: [Should composer.lock be committed to version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12896780/55075)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How can you test that a core update (or any other dependency that gets updated) doesn't break things in the projects using it if the developer don't do this step themselves?

That's why the usual workflow is expecting the `composer update` being run on a development machine having enough RAM (i.e. probably more than 1GB set as memory limit for PHP), and the update should be triggered manually by the developer (and if triggered automatically by a continuous integration build, the memory requirements apply to this machine as well).

There is no way around this memory requirement. A web server with only 512 MB RAM installed might be able to function as a staging server with barely any concurrent users present, but it shouldn't be used to update the Composer dependencies.

Personally I fix the merge conflicts in the `composer.lock` with a very easy system: Delete the lock file and run `composer update`. This will update all dependencies to the latest versions that satisfy the version requirements, and create a new working `composer.lock` file that get's committed during the merge.

I am not afraid to potentially update everything, because either it works as expected, or my tests will catch errors quickly.

I do select the 3rd party packages I use carefully:

- they have to tag their versions, preferably using semantic versioning.
- I do not use any branches for release versions (the rare occasions that someone used them during development were painful)
- they should ship a new major version if they make backwards incompatible changes
- the locally developed packages also follow these requirements

This works with around 270 packages served by our local Satis instance (probably also a factor to consider when trying to reduce memory footprint - only the packages known to Composer can end up in memory: Compare the ten thousand packages potentially available on packagist.org with 270 local packages). 60 packages of the 270 are locally developed by 20 developers, and randomly releasing new versions. The update failures in the last 2 years are very rare, and should be handled like other bugs: If a tagged version is detected to be incompatible, we release a bugfix release reverting the change, and tag the original change with a new major release, if the incompatible change is necessary.

So the workflow you ask for is probably like this:

- Anytime, any developer should be able to run `composer update` on their local machine.
- They should be able to detect if this breaks things on their local machine.
- If nothing is broken, they commit the changes including the `composer.lock` file to Git
- The staging server only runs `composer install` and will use exactly the versions that the developer used on his machine.
- If nothing is broken on staging, that version is ready to be used on production.

Merging an already committed version on another developers machine will likely show merge conflicts with `composer.lock`.

- Resolve conflicts on all other files.
- The `composer.lock` file should be deleted.
- From here, the workflow is like above, i.e.:
- The developer should be able to run `composer update` on his local machine.
- They should be able to detect if this breaks things on his local machine.
- If nothing is broken... and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We also use strict versioning for our packages and only update them after testing locally.
I just looked it up and you can update your composer.lock file easily by running : $ composer update --lock
So this way we can solve the local merge conflicts on composer.lock

Any idea why a pull on the server sometimes fails because of merge conflicts on composer.lock?

Comment: *The composer.lock file should be deleted.* What about a new package added? Deleting composer.lock lead to lost work from another developer.

Comment: To properly handle merge conflicts with composer.lock is difficult.  Deleting the file *is not the solution*, since this will may install different versions from what other developers are using.  The composer.lock file is designed to track which versions are installed and should be committed to git.

See: http://blog.theodo.fr/2013/03/resolving-composer-merge-conflicts/

Comment: @LukeH ...three years after that answer was written, better practices emerge. On the other hand, projects which regularly update their dependencies and have enough tests to find resulting bugs are less likely to be affected by a merge conflict even if the steamroller tactics of deleting the lock file during merge is applied.

Comment: @felipsmartins. If a new package has been added, it should be in `composer.json`. Running a full update will create a new `composer.lock` file which includes everything from `composer.json`.

Comment: deleting `composer.lock` and running `composer update` making life easy for me +1

Comment: You don't need to delete `composer.lock` before running `update` - it'll overwrite the conflicted version by default.

Answer (score 19):

Another approach (without doing `composer update`):

1. Copy your new (and deleted) lines from `composer.json` into a separate text file.
2. Use entire remote `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files.
3. During merge conflict mode do:

   - `composer install`
   - For every new package your wrote down in step 1 run `composer require vendor/package:version`
   - For every removed package your wrote down in step 1 run `composer remove vendor/package`
4. Testing!, Commiting, done!

This method will keep locks from remote branch (maybe `master` or `develop` branches), and only updates your new packages.

Comment: IMO this is a safer option, doing `composer update` on large projects can be counterproductive. I also prefer to just accept all changes to composer files from upstream, then introduce my composer.json changes one by one via `composer require`

I would say this is the safest approach and works always.

Answer (score 4):

Sometime `composer update` can break things.
What I do is.

1. Discard all of my changes on `composer.lock`
2. Merge `composer.json`
3. Run `composer install` so that packages get installed according to `composer.lock`.
4. Take one of your package and run `composer require vendor/package` if you
   added that package or `composer remove vendor/package` if you removed it.
   if there are multiple packages it will be installed automatically from `composer.json`

Comment: Pretty much the same as the previous answer from @Xover

Answer (score 0):

To fix conflicts in composer.lock, you can follow the steps below:

- Get rid of the Git confusion (the HEAD, == and << characters, and
  everything else on those lines.
- Pick one of the two content-hash values (it doesn’t matter which)
- Run this command: composer update --lock

Reference: https://mikemadison.net/blog/2020/8/18/resolving-composerlock-git-merge-conflicts

Hope it helps :)