# Re-install vendors from composer.lock (not composer.json)

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, vendors

In my project I have some ***Composer* vendor** libraries that have been **manually edited**; my purpose is to **restore them to the original state**, on my development machine.

I unfortunately triggered a `composer update` so I don't have a correct *composer.lock* anymore (it has been updated). I got the *composer.lock* from our production system (that had the same libraries version of the old development *composer.lock*).

After replacing the new *composer.lock* with the old one, what should I execute for being sure to have the same environment as before?

Should `composer install` be enough to reinstall the old versions of the dependencies? (after removing the old *Composer* **vendor/** directory)

I want to reinstall without getting any newer version.
And, in future cases where I will avoid to perform a `composer update`, **what should I have triggered for restoring a vendor library after a manual edit of it?**

Comment: [Yes, `composer install` will use the `composer.lock` file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896780/composer-lock-part-of-the-repository#comment17467626_12896850)

Comment: Oh thanks. I couldn't find where it was already discussed. Do you think it will work also with a restored *composer.lock* from another machine (different machine but with the same project and in the desired state)?

Comment: Exactly. The command `install` looks for the `composer.lock` file and will download the versions specified there. The only risk with a restored version is that maybe it's an older version therefore installing older dependencies. Have a look here: [composer.lock - The Lock File](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file)

Comment: Send composer.lock to your git/svn. Ever you upgrade or install new dependencies, the  composer.lock will be updated and you have to send this to your git/svn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As answered from *Max*:

["Yes, `composer install` will use the `composer.lock` file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896780/composer-lock-part-of-the-repository#comment17467626_12896850)

I just restored the `composer.lock` from my production system and then performed a `composer install`.

As stated from *Édipo Costa Rebouças*, if we commit the `composer.lock` to our repository every time we update it then we will always have the right reference to the correct versions of the dependencies.