# Git - Should Pipfile.lock be committed to version control?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

When two developers are working on a project with different operating systems, the `Pipfile.lock` is different (especially the part inside `host-environment-markers`).

[For PHP, most people recommend to commit `composer.lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896780/should-composer-lock-be-committed-to-version-control) file.

Do we have to do the same for Python?

Comment: Usually you just commit `requirements.txt` and exclude everything else (`env/` typically).

Comment: Do I need `requirements.txt` if I am using Pipenv? the Pipfile should be enough?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Short - Yes!

The lock file tells pipenv exactly which version of each dependency needs to be installed. You will have consistency across all machines.

// update: [Same question on github](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/598)

Comment: Thanks for the explainations

Comment: The main maintainer of pipenv also recommends to commit the file (especially for applications): https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/issues/598

Comment: Are we assuming here that the OS & architecture is the same across machines?

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, you should not commit `Pipfile.lock` because:

- It will contain info on a specific build of each library. Those builds could be platform-dependent, and you don't want to share them with other developers and between environments (potentially).
- It will cache your credentials used locally to install packages from private feeds.

Just a regular `Pipfile` should probably be enough.

Comment: Where does the lock file cache the credentials? Other than if you use a package repo URL of the form `schema://username:password@host/path`, I don't know how it does.