# Composer: lock file and Git

Tags: git, composer-php

I've created a staging version of an application, mirroring what I have in development. However, I had a few problems with the routing on staging and one suggestion was to run `composer update`.

Since doing that I've made changes on development and I'm now one commit ahead of the repo, and by extension — staging.

What I wasn't aware of at the time was that the "composer.lock" file had been updated on staging.

I understand that I do need to keep the changes in the lock file on staging.

What would be the best course of action in this scenario?

In more explicit terms: What steps would I need to follow to avoid conflicts with Git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should composer.lock be committed to version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896780/should-composer-lock-be-committed-to-version-control)

Comment: That answers part of the question, but not how I resolve the potential issues with Git.

Comment: Which are the potential issues? In your staging system, you should never run `composer update`, but do this in your dev environment and then commit the new lock file

Comment: Yeah, I know that now, but now I have a lock file with changes, plus a bunch of updates to the Composer packages. I need to reconcile staging with development without screwing up the repo.