# Can't clone from BitBucket using SSH

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-bash, git-clone

I have no choice I must use git clone with ssh so after that when I use composer install it will downlonad some dependencies from bitbucket using git clone ssh
when I try run git clone using SSH,

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:namespace/project.git
```

I get this output

```
Cloning into 'project'...
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.141.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Could not create directory '/home/user/.ssh' (No such file or directory).
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts).
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do not know from where it get RSA key fingerprint  `SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A`
when generated private key and public key using the command line ssh-keygen and I got RSA key fingerprint `SHA256:xV8l3qRhTRnFgRrZly1+ygQP9fqoANzqbuaYAVO1j9M`

I also added the public key in bitbucket account and added a line known_hosts (bitbucket.org,104.192.141.1 ssh-rsa public key... ), but still no use.

Comment: I'm interesting to know, I have the same problem plzzz

Comment: Are you using GitBash or Cygwin? Does the directory `/home/user/.ssh` actually exist?

Comment: I am using windows and yes I use GitBash

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment where your %userprofile% path is set to a network drive?  By default in Windows, the SSH keys created by will be stored in C:\users\\[your user]\.ssh.  This should be what maps to the '/home/[your user]/.ssh' path in the output above.  The message indicates that the .ssh directory could not be found and could not be created - you could try to manually create that directory if your Git Bash can't create it.  In my experience it's to be created in the %userprofile% directory. HTH! :)

Comment: yes .ssh directory does exist and  /home/[user]/.ssh points on  c:/users/[user]/.ssh when use commands like ssh-keygen  and ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org both commands work

Comment: Be aware that Git-for-Windows includes its own separate ssh implementation, which it will use instead of the system ssh. There are numerous ways to deal with this; see [this serverfault.com question](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I found is to use git clone https and in composer.lock file I modified all lines with "url": "git@bitbucket.org:namespace/package.git" to "url": "https://myusername:mypassword@bitbucket.org/namespace/package.git"

Comment: I strongly advise against putting your username and password in the *composer.lock* file! This file should be checked-in and committed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12896780/5024726)). You definitely don't want your credentials in a Git repository.

Comment: yeah, I agree with you Matt, I had no choice, I reverted the changes in composer.loc after executing the command composer install

Comment: Worked for me thank's a million bro you saved meee!

Answer (score 0):

Cloning via HTTPS worked for me by creating an app password.

[image]

Related link:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/set-password-when-using-google-authentication/qaq-p/967729

So from

```
$ git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
Cloning into 'xxx'...
Enter Bitbucket credentials for 'https://bitbucket.org/'...
Username: xxx
Password:
fatal: Invalid credentials
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git/'
```

To:

```
$ git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
Cloning into 'xxx'...
Enter Bitbucket credentials for 'https://bitbucket.org/'...
Username: xxx
Password:
remote: Enumerating objects: 2073, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2073/2073), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (795/795), done.
remote: Total 2073 (delta 1153), reused 1648 (delta 899), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (2073/2073), 23.65 MiB | 1.76 MiB/s, done.     
Resolving deltas: 100% (1153/1153), done.
```